# Laravel groupBy then return one result with the highest count

Tags: php, laravel, max

I have an `expenses` table, that has a `belongsTo` relation with `Descriptions`. I simply want to return the description instance that was used the most. What my thoughts are, is to grab the `description_id` that was used the most, then grab the corresponding `Description` from the database using the id. So far I came up with this:

```
auth()->user()->expenses()->get()->groupBy('description_id');
```

So this gives me the results grouped by `description_id`. Unsure if I'm on the right track, but not sure where to go from here. Or if there is a more appropriate way to accomplish this. Anything that can lead me into the right direction will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an `expenses` relationship set up in your `Description` model and a `user` relationship set up in your `Expense` model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood correctly, i think the following should work:

```
DB::table('expenses')
    ->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id)
    ->groupBy('description_id')
    ->orderByRaw('count(*) DESC')
    ->value('description_id')
    ->first();
```

That would return the `description_id` of the most popular expense.

Comment: Had to change the `->select` to `->value` for my case and remove the `->first()`, but it works like a charm, thnx :)

Comment: Edited the answer. I just learned about `value()` too. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

You can try this way :

```
$userWithExpensesWithMaxDescription = auth()->user()->expenses()->with(['descriptions' => function ($query) {
    // subquery to get only max count
    $query->select('description_id', DB::raw('count(*) as total'))
        ->groupBy('description_id')
        ->orderBy('total', 'DESC')
        ->first();
}])->get();
```

I suppose you have relation `descriptions` in your `Expenses` model.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an `expenses` relationship set up in your `Description` model and a `user` relationship set up in your `Expense` model you could do something like:

```
$description = Description::withCount([
    'expenses' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
    }])
    ->orderBy('expenses_count', 'desc')
    ->first();
```